# How to set start day of a calendar application

Tags: javascript, extjs

We all know how to set start day of a date picker. It is as simple as:

```
 startDay : Number
```

But what I want is to set start day of `Ext.calendar.App` to Monday. Now on week and month panels the first day is Sunday. So, how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you referring to the new calendar component in 6.2, or the calendar example?

Comment: I'm referrring to calendar application example. But it seems like I've found  a solution. I had to override `Ext.calendar.view.AbstractCalendar` property `startDay`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is calendar api:

http://ext.ensible.com/deploy/dev/docs/#!/api/Extensible.calendar.CalendarPanel-cfg-startDay

But Ext.picker.Date should set start day for all other components. Try to override this startDate value.

Comment: Well, the problem is I'm not using ensible extensions.